# Criar botão de avançar

Tags: jsp, java

Estou com um problema que não encontrei nenhuma solução, estou tentando criar um botão de avançar para passar as paginas do meu arquivo .pdf que é exibido na minha pagina JSP.

```
        String arquivo = ""; 
        String i = "";
        try {
            arquivo = request.getParameter("nomeArq");
            if (arquivo.equals("()null") || arquivo.equals("null") || arquivo.equals("")) {
                arquivo = request.getAttribute("nomeArquivo").toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            arquivo = request.getAttribute("nomeArquivo").toString();
        }
        try {
            i = request.getParameter("numeroPag").toString();
            if (i.equals("()null") || i.equals("null") || i.equals("")) {
                i = request.getAttribute("pagina").toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception a) {
            i = request.getAttribute("pagina").toString();
        }
```

Onde "arquivo" é o nome do arquivo a ser aberto e "i" é o numero da pagina que será aberta a pagina. No inicio o valor de "i" é 1, mas se o usuário clicar em avançar ele é direcionado para uma outra página JSP onde faço a troca do valor de "i" e depois retorno para o JSP de visualização do pdf. Na minha pagina JSP de avançar a página fiz assim:

```
        String p = request.getParameter("NumPag");
        int pagina = Integer.parseInt(p) + 1;
        request.setAttribute("pagina", pagina);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("VisualizarPDF.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Mas sempre que clico no botão avançar ocorre o erro `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Já depurei o código e o erro ocorre quando tento pegar o valor da pagina JSP Avancar, mas não sei o motivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui descobrir o erro, precisava passar o nome do arquivo pra pagina JSP Avancar também